# Prove $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, radicals

As in the title:

Prove $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

It seems so simple, but I can't seem to do it without ending up in circular reasoning.

Comment: A tip for the next time: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[limits]+sqrt...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** : $$\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite your expression as: $$ \frac{n^{1/2}}{n}   \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{1/2}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}  $$. As n goes to $\infty$ the expression of the secon fraction is a known limit that is equal to $1/2$. So you get as n goes to $\infty$ $1/2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ that goues to zero.